# How to access specific object in an array of DOM objects in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Ok so I wanna ask a simple jQuery question about arrays of objects.

If I get all elements (for example all paragraphs) from an html page and store them in an array how can I access one of them to do stuff with it?

For example let's say I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title> 
    </head>
    <body> 
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <button id="myButton">Click here</button>

    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){

        var $paragraphs = $("p"); 
        $paragraphs.detach();  //Works fine, removes all elements
        //$paragraphs[0].detach();  //Doesn't work!

    }); 
});
```

I'm trying to call detach on the first element of the array, so that I can remove the first paragraph but it doesn't seem to work...

Is there any way to access the first paragraph without using id attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$($paragraphs[0]).detach();
```

When you pass a index to the jQuery Object List `$paragraphs[0]` , the object becomes a
 **DOM Object**

```
var $paragraphs = $("p"); 

var domObj = $paragraphs[0];

var jqueryObj = $(domObj);
```

So you need to wrap it again as a jQuery Object ..

Instead  you can use the `:eq()` selector

```
var $paragraph = $("p:eq(0)");  // Selects only the first para
                                 // which is a jQuery Object
$paragraph.detach();   // This works too
```

Comment: The `eq()` function may be faster, as I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13943411/61754).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to select the first element:

```
$("p:eq(0)").detach();
```

This will detach just the first element.

You could instead use the [`.eq()` function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), which may offer better performance:

```
$("p").eq(0).detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$paragraphs[0]` will unwrap the jquery object into the html element which is why you cannot access `detach` ( a jquery function ).

You should either iterate through the paragraphs, or re-wrap the object. This should work

```
var detachParagraph = $paragraphs[0];
$(detachParagraph).detach();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a filter function:
    $("p").filter(function(index){
        if(index==0){
            $(this).detach();
        }
    )};

Comment: -1 for being too cumbersome. Use `eq` as mentioned by other answers.